# Would joining pads of a pi-filter eliminate impedance changes from line to pad? Would it cause problems with alignment during reflow?

Tags: pcb, filter, impedance-matching

This is a 2 part question:

1. Would joining the pads, such as on the lower pi-filter pictured, cause any problems with alignment of the components during reflow soldering?
2. Would joining the pads result in less loss of the signal? I am wondering if joining the pads would prevent losses or reflections from changes in impedance which would occur in the two gaps between the thin transmission line and the thicker pads, shown by the neon green arrows. On my board the transmission line will be 50Ω and the pads will be 26Ω. Would the impedance changes in the gaps cause losses or reflections? If there are losses, how significant would they be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer the part of the reflow-soldering, I lack some knowledge about impedance.

Joining the pads that way will definitely cause problems during reflow soldering. The problem will be tomb-stoning. This is when a component is standing upright (feet up in the air) on the PCB during reflow soldering.

The components will float to the centre of the pad based on the force of the solder-paste.
For the horizontal component this will probably not be an issue because both pads are the same size so the force applied on both sides is the same (however too strong forces will result in tomb-stoning too).
For the two vertical components the side on the joined pads will float to the centre (the force is stronger on the larger pad than the force on the smaller one). Resulting in a shift and tombstone of the components.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, and I guess that solves the question then, because indeed the vertical components would be highly prone to tombstoning with one pad much larger and applying a significantly uneven force with the solder, as you said. So the idea is not acceptable to begin with.